# What role do I need to be in order to create an app?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I was added to a client's Vimeo account as an Admin. I need to create an app so I can access the api, as described here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start

I have created apps just fine in the past by following this link: https://developer.vimeo.com/apps/new

However when I am logged in as an admin on this account, it give me a permissions error:

Permission Denied

Sorry but you do not have the proper permission to access this area of Vimeo.

Are Admins not permissioned to create an app? If so, what roles can?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently only the primary account holder can create and manage apps for a parent PRO or Business account. Users who are set as Admins, Contributors, or Uploaders of a parent account cannot manage developer apps for that account.

Reason being is that by using the API, a user could modify that parent account's settings and metadata outside of the on-site team member structure.

Vimeo may change this in the future, but there's no ETA for supporting team members at this time.

An overview of team member management can be found in the Vimeo Help Center: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224818687-Managing-team-members-on-your-account

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming. I'm new to SE so my vote isn't showing up, but you have it.

Comment: @Brian: you shouldn't just upvote it, you should *accept* the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @jmrk I don't see a way to do that. Maybe I don't get that option because I am so new?

Comment: It sounds like you should always have that option: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: What is meant by "Admins of another PRO or Business account"?

Comment: @showdev You know, I'm surprised no one else noticed that until now. Editing my answer so it makes sense, thanks for the heads up.